Why won't my LED lights on a motion switch turn off completely?
My new motion control switch is acting oddly. I originally had an incandescent dimmer switch running two Incandescent candelabra lights over a mirror in a bathroom. One of these lights burned out, and I decided to replace it with two candelabra type dimmer LEDs on  an LED-compatible motion sensing dimmer switch. The original dimmer has yellow and red wires and one green wire to the metal junction box. No neutral was present. Another switches present which controls the fan.

The new switch was wired Yellow to line and red to load with Green to grounded box. No neutral, and the burned out bulb replaced with an LED thus leaving one incandescent bulb. The switch works perfectly with the motion sensing and timer good.

I then replaced the remaining incandescent with a second dimmable LED. Now, neither light will turn off completely although the motion detector and timer work. The behavior is similarly wonky if one of the LEDs is removed leaving one empty socket.

Reversing the yellow and red leads results in identical behavior.

The voltage between the leads is 48-64V on my Klein mini volt meter. There is no voltage demonstrated between either lead and the metal junction box which is part of the original metal conduit wiring of the house.


The easiest thing to do I suppose is replace the LED bulbs with the original incandescent, but I would still like to understand the problem.

Where does the 48-64V reading come from in a 120V house? Voltage drop from being in series with the lights?

Why would one incandescent bulb together with one LED work properly?

Does the 0 voltage between leads and box suggest the box is not grounded?


Dimmer
LIDOR
LPDS-3W-WWP
COLOR: WHITE | QTY.: 1 PACK
Occupancy/ Vacancy Dimmer Sensor
Switch And Matte Finish Mid-size 1 Gang Decorator/GFCI Plastic Wall Plates
Voltage: 120VAC, 60Hz
Tungsten/Incandescent: 600W
Electronic Self-Ballast (LED): 150W

Technically there are no fully compatible switches. Some LEDs work with some switches. You may just need to try other brands or look for compatibility tables from the manufacturers. Also look at the many similar questions on this site (an ideal first step).

Quite a few questions on here about LEDs not turning off completely with some dimmers.  I think most of it is about low voltage being pass through to the lights.  LEDs are dim, but there is not enough power to light an incandescent light.

Your switch has electronics inside which need to be powered. But it doesn't connect to the Neutral wire to be able to power itself 'conventionally', so instead it 'leaks' a little current between it's Line and Load wires. The only way for this current to flow is through the load device(s) - your light bulbs. This current is not enough to light up an incandescent bulb, but since LEDs are much more efficient, it is enough to light them up a little.

@brhans that's an answer...put it down below.

use different LED bulbs, most newer ones have resistors built-in to power active switches w/o ghost flickering the LEDs.

A powered switch that has to get power from somewhere to do its dimmer and motion sensor functions.  Supply and lamp wires are interchangeable.  No neutral connection is made.
All this adds up to a switch which is powering its own electronics by leaking current through the bulbs.  That's a completely normal way that dimmers and other powered switches have been powering themselves for 60 years.
Incandescents never minded, they are nearly a dead short when unlit, and the leakage isn't enough to light them up.  That's why one incandescent in the circuit takes care of it.   However once you cut it back to all LED, the leakage WAS enough to light them due to their efficiency.
The fix is a LUT-MLC, a module which emulates the conductance of incandescent bulbs, allowing the powered switch to pass its current. Or those dimmer-rated LED bulbs which have functionally a LUT-MLC built into themselves for this purpose.
